# Missing value auth-url required for auth plugin password

Tags: openstack

I am trying to install openstack using devstack on ubuntu 16.04.
I followed the following link.

> https://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/guides/single-machine.html

When I run

> sudo openstack service list

, it prompt the following error.

> Missing value auth-url required for auth plugin password

Comment: Run the following commands in sequence.    cd devstack ,  source openrc                                         export OS_TENANT_NAME=$OS_PROJECT_NAME ,                  openstack  service list

Answer (score 33):

Make sure you are logged into horizon and download the rc file (right corner). After that do `source admin-openrc.sh`

Note that you have to download the rc file of the project you are working on

Comment: thank you for this. as a n00b in the openstack space this step is very rarely referenced, though critical.

Comment: Saved me with this one, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

always run `admin-openrc` file before running any openstack command
eg.

`$source admin-openrc`

then run whatever openstack command you want to run

eg.

`$openstack --debug server list`

Comment: you need to download `admin-openrc` from dashboard GUI

Answer (score 4):

This should do. `keystonerc_admin` file is generated at the end of openstack packstack installation

`source keystonerc_admin`

Comment: it also could be `source openrc`. I have a fresh installation and it does not create `keystonerc_admin` by default (i searched the entire disk, no entries for that). The installation only create `openrc` and `stackrc` (stack is the name of my user that I manually created before installation).

Answer (score 0):

Take rocky version of OpenStack Keystone as an example. https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/rocky/install/keystone-openrc-rdo.html#using-the-scripts

You can create an admin-openrc.sh (If you are installing OpenStack Keystone for the first time.) and put environment params. And source this file before you run any "openstack" command. This resolves the issue.

I put the admin-openrc.sh in directory /usr/share/keystone/admin-openrc.sh for a recommend.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with:
**cd devstack** and then **source openrc**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).