# Missing value auth-url required for auth plugin password in Devstack while creating an image using terminal

Tags: devstack

I have gone through this post [Missing value auth-url required for auth plugin password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42844649/missing-value-auth-url-required-for-auth-plugin-password), but it does not resolve my issue.

I have a fresh installation and I have only `openrc` and `stackrc`.  It is throwing the error in all the cases including `sudo openstack service list`.

How can I create `admin-openrc` if it resolves the issue?  Could someone please help me on that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can source the `openrc` in your DevStack directory (assuming it lies under `/opt/stack`):

```
source /opt/stack/devstack/openrc admin
```

Alternatively, you may create *your own* `openrc` with this content (adapt according to your settings):

```
export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME=Default
export OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME=Default
export OS_PROJECT_NAME=admin
export OS_USERNAME=admin
export OS_PASSWORD=ADMIN_PASS
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://controller/identity/v3
```